# What can cause fetch() to return success, but subsequently accessing the body to throw TypeError or AbortError?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) for getting some resources from the server. I can see from logs that from time to time [obtaining the JSON body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) fails on `"TypeError: Failed to fetch"`, which is very interesting because this type of error should only happen when the request fails.

The simplified code I use:

```js
const response = await fetch('https://something.com/api')

try {
  // below throws TypeError: Failed to fetch in Chrome/Safari
  // and AbortError in Firefox
  await response.json();
} catch(error) {
  console.log('error happened', error);
}
```

I cannot really find a case when this might happen. I tested a number of plausible scenarios and all failed on the first line of code, i.e. `fetch('https:/something.com/api')`. I have no idea when this might happen. I also should mention that it happens in modern browsers like Chrome 99, so it is not definitely something like Internet Explorer thing.

I found this useful example and it shows that requests are cancelled when you unload the document. Obviously, cancellation happens on the `fetch` line but I decided to stop logging these errors when the document is unloaded/hidden. Even when these cases are not logged I can see it happens on visible documents too.

https://github.com/shuding/request-cancellation-test

Cases tested:

1. Network error - user disconnected from the internet
2. CORS - missing CORS headers

Obviously, this does not prove anything but people in the comments think that I do something wrong in implementation and do not trust me when I say it indeed happens when obtaining the JSON body. This is the information I am able to log when I catch the error. Most properties are from the [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object.

This is the log captured from visitor using Chrome 100. Firefox does not throw TypeError instead it throws AbortError but it also happens when converting to json.

[image: Log from Chrome 100]

Comment: Have you looked at the browser "Network" developer tool to see what's happening with the HTTP request?

Comment: the problem is that I cannot simulate it. I can see it only in my logs (sentry)

Comment: @Joozty can you upload the console like my answer, we can get too many cases for this error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a network error that happened after the response HTTP headers have already been received.  In such a situation, the `fetch` method returns success, but subsequent attempts to access the response body may fail.

I managed to trigger this kind of error with this simple server:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import http.server
import time

class Handler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.wfile.write(b'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n')
            self.wfile.write(b'Content-type: text/html\r\n')
            self.wfile.write(b'\r\n')
            self.wfile.write(b"""\
<script type="module">
    const f = await fetch("/j");
    try {
        await f.json();
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
</script>
""")
            return

        self.wfile.write(b'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n')
        self.wfile.write(b'Content-encoding: gzip\r\n')  # bogus
        self.wfile.write(b'Content-type: application/json\r\n')
        self.wfile.write(b'\r\n')
        self.wfile.write(b'[]')


server = http.server.HTTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 31337), Handler)
server.serve_forever()
```

It introduces a deliberate framing error when serving the JSON response; the headers indicate that gzip compression is employed, but no compression is actually used.  When I open `http://127.0.0.1:31337/` in Chromium 100.0.4896.127, it displays the following alert:

> TypeError: Failed to fetch

Firefox ESR 91.8.0 displays a marginally more helpful:

> TypeError: Decoding failed.

The particular framing error demonstrated above is rather contrived, and I doubt it is exactly the kind that the asker experienced.  But the fact that it appeared in the middle of the response body is probably at the heart of the described problem.

The specific pair of error types from the question can be triggered by modifying the server thus:

```python
        self.wfile.write(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n')
        self.wfile.write(b'Content-type: application/json\r\n')
        # sic: larger than the actual body length
        self.wfile.write(b'Content-length: 2\r\n')
        self.wfile.write(b'\r\n')
        self.wfile.write(b'[')
```

This displays the same alert:

> TypeError: Failed to fetch

in Chromium (same version), and

> AbortError: The operation was aborted.

in Firefox (also same).

As such, a likely cause would be a flaky connection dropped in the middle of receiving the body.  The browsers’ errors are not particularly detailed here (and sometimes are downright misleading), so we are resigned to speculate, but this seems like the best guess.

Answer (score -3):

Your error from this line:

```js
const response = await fetch('https://something.com/api')
```

I removed `await response.json()` to test, the error still exists.

Please look console tab in DevTool, make sure that you use this setting[image]

These are 2 example errors `Failed to fetch`:

```js
(async () => {

try {
    const response = await fetch('http://my-api.com/example')
    await response.json() 
} catch (e) {
    console.log('e')
    console.log(e)
}
})()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please use code instead of images (where possible), which helps screen-readers.

Comment: @ArnavThorat His problem is `fetch...` line.

Comment: The examples you showed fail on fetch... not on `response.json()` line.  I cannot accept this answer.

Comment: @Joozty Can you use this setting, re-run your code and upload console tab, I believe the error cause is `fetch(...)`, not `response.json()`

Comment: You mean settings in console? I already have it like that and I am pretty sure the error is coming from `response.json()`

Comment: @Joozty Can you share API was called? If not, please try-catch each line to know what like make this error